# Security implication of non-free drivers

Tags: linux, security, debian, drivers

I was wondering what the security implications are of using non-free drivers on a linux laptop. Especially for graphics and wifi.

Comment: Not related directly to programming. Try super-user or https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you are concerned about. Plus it is easier to hack into a wifi network through wifi itself thant through the wifi adapter driver.

Regarding Graphics, unless you are displaying million dollar data, I wouldnt be concerned about any security breach

Comment: I am displaying million dollar data, and transmitting it in encrypted form over wifi.

Comment: well if it is realy worth millon dollar data, dont use wifi. Regarding graphic driver, what driver are you talking about ?